how to display selected filter values with unselected and clear all with mixitup
This code is instance, perform search, and filter.
I want to display selected/checked values from left side filter box to be displayed on the top of the list items with cancel sign and clear all.


jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    // Declare keyup timeout.
    var keyupTimeout;
      var rsmixer = mixitup('#resource-filter-mixer', {
        controls: {
            enable: true,
            toggleLogic: 'or'
        },
        animation: {
            effects: 'fade'
        },
        pagination: {
            limit: 10,
        },
        callbacks: {
            onPaginateStart: function(state, futureState) {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $('.rs-scroll-point').offset().top - 100
                }, 'slow');
            }
        }
    });

    $('.rs-filter-box #search').on('keypress',function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            //alert('You pressed enter!');

            var searchValue;

            if ( this.value.length < 3 ) {
            // If the input value is less than 3 characters, don't send
                searchValue = '';
            } else {
                searchValue = this.value.toLowerCase().trim();
            }
            //console.log('searchbox: '+searchValue);
            // Very basic throttling to prevent mixer thrashing. Only search
            // once 350ms has passed since the last keyup event
            clearTimeout( keyupTimeout );
        
            keyupTimeout = setTimeout( function() {
                filterByString( searchValue );
            }, 350 );
      
        }
    });

    $('.rs-filter-box input').on('change', function() {

        // reset the search if a filter is clicked
        //$('#search').val('');
        var filterx = '<div id="fancy_icon-2186-10440" class="ct-fancy-icon"><svg id="svg-fancy_icon-2186-10440"><use xlink:href="#FontAwesomeicon-close"></use></svg></div>';
        $('.filterbox').html( $(this).val() + filterx );
        
        var rsfilterString = [];
        $('.rs-filter-box input:checked').each(function () {
            rsfilterString.push($(this).val());
        });
        //alert(rsfilterString);
        rsfilterString = rsfilterString.join(',');
        if(!rsfilterString || /^\s*$/.test(rsfilterString)){
            rsfilterString = "*";
        }
        //console.log(rsfilterString);
        rsmixer.filter(rsfilterString, true,function(){
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('.rs-scroll-point').offset().top - 100
            }, 'slow');
        });
        
    });

    function getUrlVars()
    {
        var vars = [], hash;
        var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
        {
            hash = hashes[i].split('=');
            vars.push(hash[0]);
            vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
        }
        return vars;
    }

    $( window ).on( "load", function() {
        
        var QueryStringData = getUrlVars()["t"];
        if(QueryStringData!=''){
            
            //alert(QueryStringData);
            //$(".rs-filter-box .checkbox").find("#"+QueryStringData).trigger('change');
            $("#"+QueryStringData).trigger('click');
            // Handler for .ready() called.
            /*$('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#qodef-page-content').offset().top
            }, 'slow');*/
            //$('.loading').hide();
        }
        
    });

    function filterByString( searchValue ) {

        if ( searchValue ) {
            //console.log('filterstr: '+searchValue);
            // Use an attribute wildcard selector to check for matches
            rsmixer.filter( '[class*="' + searchValue + '"], [data-title*="' + searchValue + '"]' );
        } else {
            // If no searchValue, treat as filter('all')
            //rsmixer.filter( 'all' );
        }
    }
});



I want to display selected/checked values from left side filter box to be displayed on the top of the list items with cancel sign and clear all.
I attached a example image.
ref website
Currently i am trying to do on my website here- 
